# Is there an alternative for Ansible's `become: yes`?

Tags: ansible, sudo

I want to run an Ansible playbook to provision a server. I can ssh into the server as a non-root user. I have sudo privileges, but I am not allowed to switch to root user. I effectively just want to execute `sudo mkdir /opt/some_directory` (the command works when I ssh in and execute the command on the server).

Using `become:true` produces the error of trying to switch to root user and then creating the directory, I think.

The Code:

```
- name: "Info: Creating directory."
  become: true
  file:
    path: "{{ directory }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

The error I am getting is `Sorry, user xxxxx is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS...`

Answer (score 0):

> Q: "Is there an alternative for Ansible's become: yes? I have sudo privileges, but I am **not allowed to switch to root** user. I effectively just **want to execute sudo mkdir /opt/some_directory** ..."

A: No. Quoting from [Can’t limit escalation to certain commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#can-t-limit-escalation-to-certain-commands)

> "**Privilege escalation permissions have to be general**...  If you have ‘/sbin/service’ or ‘/bin/chmod’ as the **allowed commands this will fail** "...